# How to create a project in Android Studio for Amazon Fire TV Stick

Tags: android, android-studio, amazon-fire-tv

I am having a hard time trying to create a new Project for Amazon Fire TV Stick.
I added the Amazon Fire TV SDK to Android Studio, as shown in the following link:

[Setting Up Your Development Environment](https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/resources/development-tools/ide-tools/tech-docs/01-setting-up-your-development-environment)

I installed the new Options:
[image: SDK Plattforms]

[image: SDK Tools]

My Problem is that I am not able to create a Amazon Fire TV Stick Project. I also
wasn´t able to find a tutorial for that. There is NO option for an Amazon FTVS 
project type.

So Please tell me, what am I doing wrong.

Comment: you should be targeting FireOS5 / Android 5.1 (level 22) with AndroidTV and Leanback Library (v17)

Comment: So I don´t need the FTVS SDK right?

Comment: from the getting started there's no mention of needing a specific SDK any more. Previous FireTV OS versions did need their SDK but it looks like it's more mainstream Android now

Answer (score 1):

As [Offbeatmammal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1569675/offbeatmammal) mentioned, there is no specific project configuration or SDK required when developing for Amazon Fire TV Stick.

Amazon Fire TV Stick runs on [Amazon Fire OS 3.0, which is based on Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean), API Level 17](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/device-and-platform-specifications). So you just need to ensure your app support API level 17, as well as [user input from the Amazon Fire TV Remote](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/supporting-controllers-on-amazon-fire-tv).